# Trigger Share site when item is added to list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online

I want to be able to add a new users details to a list, keeping it really simple with FirstName, Surname and email address to users list.

Once they have been added I want the "Share Site" process to start automatically, using the email address which was added, is this even possible without writing code?

My Environment is SP2010 online.

Regards,

S

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a sandboxed event receiver or you could try it with standard workflow but i am not sure if sharing/permissions are available in standard workflows.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Max, not sure myself will keep digging.